# displaying integers in android using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, decimal

I have a database that contains decimals.  The column is set up as ".. decimal(5,2) not null.  What I'm trying to do is to find the sum of the column and displaying it in a text field by using this code..

```
public int getTotal() {

 Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase2.rawQuery(
            "SELECT SUM(thedata) FROM thetable", null);
 if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     return cursor.getInt(0);
     }
 return cursor.getInt(0);

}
```

However, when returned the value is a whole number.  It should be something like 20.75 instead of just 20.

I'm not very familiar with SQLite, so please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of Xperimental's answer, you are calling `getInt()` on the `Cursor`, and you are returning and int from `getTotal()`. Here, `int` is shorthand for integer, what you refer to as a "whole number". If you want floating-point values, use `getFloat()` and return a `float` or `Float`.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite doesn't know the datatype `DECIMAL`, so it could be possible, that it defaults back to the `INTEGER` datatype it knows. Try to use another datatype, which is recognized by SQLite. The datatypes SQLite knows can be found on the following page:
http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Looking back on the answer, I really have missed the code part containing the `getInt()` calls... weird.